# I got this function and now i want slides to display block after exacly 1 second?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this function loops trough a div called mySlides, and sets the current slide on display block and the one before, back to a display none.

```
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName("numbertext");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

I want to deley this display block for 1 second, i dont know how to setTimeOut() to such a function.

```
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bottom for loop would look like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(function(){
        slides[i - 1].style.display = "block";
    }, 1000) //time in ms
}
```